# ReactJS - Does render get called any time "setState" is called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Does React re-render all components and sub components every time `setState()` is called?

If so, why? I thought the idea was that React only rendered as little as needed - when state changed.

In the following simple example, both classes render again when the text is clicked, despite the fact that the state doesn't change on subsequent clicks, as the onClick handler always sets the `state` to the same value:

```
this.setState({'test':'me'});
```

I would've expected that renders would only happen if `state` data had changed.

Here's the code of the example, [as a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fp2tncmb/2/), and embedded snippet:

```js
var TimeInChild = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var t = new Date().getTime();

        return (
            <p>Time in child:{t}</p>
        );
    }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
    onTest: function() {
        this.setState({'test':'me'});
    },

    render: function() {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        return (
            <div onClick={this.onTest}>
            <p>Time in main:{currentTime}</p>
            <p>Click me to update time</p>
            <TimeInChild/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had the same issue, I don't know the exact solution. But I had cleaned up the unwanted codes from the component it started working as usual.

Comment: I would like to point out that in your example - because how your element is designed does not solely rely on a unique state - calling `setState()` even with dummy data does cause the element to render differently so I would say yes. Absolutely it should try to re-render your object when something might have changed because otherwise your demo - assuming it was the intended behaviour - wouldn't work!

Comment: You may be right @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen - but from my understanding, React would've rendered it the first time (since state changes from nothing to something that first time), then never had to render again. I was wrong though, of course - as it looks like React requires you to write your own `shouldComponentUpdate` method, which I assumed a simple version of it must already be included in React itself. Sounds like the default version included in react simply returns `true` - which forces the component to re-render every single time.

Comment: Yes but it only needs to re-render in the virtual DOM then it only changes the actual DOM if the component is rendered differently. Updates to the virtual DOM are usually negligible (at least compared to modifying things on the actual screen) so calling render every time it might need to update then seeing that no change has happened not very expensive and safer than assuming it should render the same.

Answer (score 673, accepted):

> Does React re-render all components and sub-components every time setState is called?

By default - yes.

There is a method **boolean shouldComponentUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState)**, each component has this method and it's responsible to determine "should component update (run *render* function)?" every time you change *state* or pass new *props* from parent component.

You can write your own implementation of *shouldComponentUpdate* method for your component, but default implementation always returns true - meaning always re-run render function.

Quote from official docs http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

> By default, shouldComponentUpdate always returns true to prevent
>   subtle bugs when the state is mutated in place, but if you are careful to
>   always treat the state as immutable and to read-only from props and state
>   in render() then you can override shouldComponentUpdate with an
>   implementation that compares the old props and state to their
>   replacements.

Next part of your question:

> If so, why? I thought the idea was that React only rendered as little as needed - when the state changed.

There are two steps of what we may call "render":

1. Virtual DOM renders: when *render* method is called it returns a new *virtual dom* structure of the component. As I mentioned before, this *render* method is called always when you call *setState()*, because *shouldComponentUpdate* always returns true by default. So, by default, there is no optimization here in React.
2. Native DOM renders: React changes real DOM nodes in your browser only if they were changed in the Virtual DOM and as little as needed - this is that great React's feature which optimizes real DOM mutation and makes React fast.

Comment: Great explanation! And the one thing that really makes React still shine in this case is that it doesn't change the *real* DOM unless the virtual DOM has been changed. So if my render function returns the same thing 2 times in a row, the real DOM doesn't get changed at all... Thanks!

Comment: Does replaceState more effective?

Comment: I think __@tungd__ is right - see his answer below. It is also a matter of a parent-child relation between components. For example if __TimeInChild__ is a sibling of __Main__ then its __render()__ will not be called unnecessarily.

Comment: If your state contains a relatively large javascript object (~1k total properties), which is rendered as a large tree of components (~100 total)... should you let the render functions construct the virtual dom, or should you, before setting the state, compare the new state to the old manually and only call `setState` if you detect there's a difference? If so, how to do this best - compare the json strings, construct and compare object hashes,...?

Comment: So, overriding  `shouldComponentUpdate ` will only have performance improvement at step#1, which only means not to reconstruct the virtual dom tree structure in some cases?

Comment: @Jaskey yes, ``shouldComponentUpdate`` help us not to recostruct the virual dom tree structure in some cases (step#1 as described above). It also means because we do not recostruct the virtual dom (when ``shouldComponentUpdate`` returned false), React under the hood do not touch the real browser DOM also (step#2) and this is a huge performance improvement!

Comment: @Petr , but even though react reconstruct the virtual dom, if the old virtual dom is the same as new virtual dom, the browser dom will not be touched , isn't it?

Comment: Also, look into using React.PureComponent (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). It only updates (re-renders) if the component's state or props have actually changed. Beware, however, that the comparison is shallow.

Comment: @Brad Parks, if due to a single component which affects the state of parent component (includes nth child - component) how react respond to this change, will it render whole dom or just the component using the state variable?

Comment: @smkrn110 - not sure - I'm not deep into React recently - I'd ask someone else! My feeling is just the component (DOM Element) that's changed

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand the last part of your explanation. does that mean React always renders a new structure of the DOM when setState is called, but unless there are actual differences visual differences than it would be updated to the actual DOM?

Comment: React doesn't re-render if you call `setState` with the same value as the current state.

Comment: That means, if you ever set the state using `setXX()` function returned from `useState()` hook using the same value for XX, then React enters an infinite loop of re-renders.

Answer (score 138):

No, React doesn't render everything when the state changes.

- Whenever a component is dirty (its state changed), that component and its children are re-rendered. This, to some extent, is to re-render as little as possible. The only time when render isn't called is when some branch is moved to another root, where theoretically we don't need to re-render anything. In your example, `TimeInChild` is a child component of `Main`, so it also gets re-rendered when the state of `Main` changes.
- React doesn't compare state data. When `setState` is called, it marks the component as dirty (which means it needs to be re-rendered). The important thing to note is that although `render` method of the component is called, the real DOM is only updated if the output is different from the current DOM tree (a.k.a diffing between the Virtual DOM tree and document's DOM tree). In your example, even though the `state` data hasn't changed, the time of last change did, making Virtual DOM different from the document's DOM, hence why the HTML is updated.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. As an experiment modify the last line as __React.renderComponent(<div><Main/><TimeInChild/></div>, document.body)__; and remove __<TimeInChild/>__ from the body of __render()__ of the __Main__ component. The __render()__ of __TimeInChild__ will not be called by default because it is not a child of __Main__ any more.

Comment: Thanks, stuff like this is a little bit tricky, that's why the React authors recommended that the `render()` method should be "pure" - independent of outer state.

Comment: @tungd, what does it mean `some branch is moved to another root`? What do you call `branch`? What do you call `root`?

Comment: I really prefer the answer marked as the correct one. I understand your interpretation of 'rendering' on the native, 'real', side... but if you look at it from the react-native side you must say that it renders again. Luckily it is smart enough to determine what really changed and only update these things. This answer might be confusing for new users, first you say no, and then you explain that things do get rendered...

Comment: @tungd can u please explain  Green's question `what does it mean some branch is moved to another root? What do you call branch? What do you call root? `

Comment: @ᚔZenOutᚔ: We call the DOM tree, root means parent element, branch means child element. I meant to describe the situation where `<ul><li/></ul><ol></ol>` -> `<ul></ul><ol><li/></ol>`, ideally it could just move the `<li/>` however most likely it will destroy the old and create a new one.

Answer (score 15):

Yes. It calls the `render()` method every time we call `setState` only except when `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `false`.

Comment: Please be more elaborative

Answer (score 12):

## React 18 and beyond

Starting from React 18 [all state updates are automatically batched](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching). In this way, React groups *multiple* state updates into a *single* re-render for better performance.

So when you update your state, React always try to batch these updates in a group update, **causing fewer *render* than `setState` calls**. The behaviour **is the same when using hooks**.

You can read the very long explanation in the [*Automatic batching for React 18* announcement](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21).

#### React 17 and below

In React 17 and below, only updates inside React event handlers are batched. Updates triggered from promises, setTimeout, native event handlers, or other events are not batched in React by default.

Answer (score 11):

Even though it's stated in many of the other answers here, the component should either:

- implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to render only when state or properties change
- switch to extending a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), which already implements a `shouldComponentUpdate` method internally for shallow comparisons.

Here's an example that uses `shouldComponentUpdate`, which works only for this simple use case and demonstration purposes. When this is used, the component no longer re-renders itself on each click, and is rendered when first displayed, and after it's been clicked once.

```js
var TimeInChild = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var t = new Date().getTime();

        return (
            <p>Time in child:{t}</p>
        );
    }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
    onTest: function() {
        this.setState({'test':'me'});
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
      if (this.state == null)
        return true;
  
      if (this.state.test == nextState.test)
        return false;
        
      return true;
  },

    render: function() {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        return (
            <div onClick={this.onTest}>
            <p>Time in main:{currentTime}</p>
            <p>Click me to update time</p>
            <TimeInChild/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the accepted answers are no longer the case when using React hooks *(with primitive values, see comments on this answer for details)*. You can see in this code sandbox that the class component is rerendered when the state is set to the same value, while in the function component, setting the state to the same value doesn't cause a rerender.

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-wave-wouk2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's because in your example, you're passing a primitive value to the useState hook and complex object to the setState method.

Try passing an object or an array to the useState hook to see re-renders in function component, because you're changing object references.

Just to clarify your example, but you're right in that using useState hook with primitive values can prevent re-rendering.

Comment: @MichalSvorc It's true that if we used an object in useState then it would also rerender, but the point is that it's impossible to use a simple primitive with the class component's `setState` function. The example is only showing the difference between using the simplest form of class component state and the simplest form of useState, and how the hooks version is (ever so slightly) more performant 

Comment: sure, I just added an explanation of why is the useState not re-rendering in your example. Someone might pass an object to the useState (which is legal) thinking that the hook will automatically prevent re-render, because you stated that "the accepted answers are no longer the case when using React hooks". Someone might not spot the difference in using a primitive and an object reference right away.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I added a minor clarification to the answer

Answer (score 5):

Another reason for "lost update" can be the next:

- If the **static getDerivedStateFromProps** is defined then it is rerun in every update process according to official documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating.
- so if that state value comes from props at the beginning it is overwrite in every update.

If it is the problem then U can avoid setting the state during update, you should check the state parameter value like this

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: TimeCorrectionProps, state: TimeCorrectionState): TimeCorrectionState {
   return state ? state : {disable: false, timeCorrection: props.timeCorrection};
}
```

Another solution is add a initialized property to state, and set it up in the first time (if the state is initialized to non null value.)

Answer (score 1):

Not All Components.

the `state` in component looks like the source of the waterfall of state of the whole APP.

So the change happens from where the setState called. The tree of `renders` then get called from there. If you've used pure component, the `render` will be skipped.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of the well explained answers here, there may be other reasons why you don't see the change you expect post changing the props or state:

Watch out for any `event.preventDefault();` in the code where you want to re-render by a state \ props change, as it will cancel any cancelable event following this statement.

Answer (score -1):

You could use setState() only after comparing the current state value and the new one and they are different.

Comment: You use setState() in order to update a local state (variables inside state) of a component. Use setState() only if the variable from state was changed and will make sense that the component renders again. You may use useRef(), if you don't want to render again the component, or you may also render again the component by using some variable and dispatch some action to force rendering the component again. In some cases is recommended to just only use let or const for managing variables. Please take also in consideration useMemo, to avoid componentes rendering again if is not required.

Comment: There is an edit button below your question that allows you to add detail to your answer after posting