# show image if stored date is not current date

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two images and got to display one of them every alternate day.
I'm using http://momentjs.com/ and checking if the storedDate = currentDate as per below code. However, I see that the state of the storeDate is not getting updated.
Could anyone shed some light here?

```
getInitialState() {
  storedDate: ''
}

onDateChanged(currentDate) {
  this.setState({ storedDate: currentDate });
},

render(){
var currentDate = moment();
var displayImage;
if (currentDate.isSame(this.state.storedDate, 'day')) {
  displayImage = Image1;
  this.onDateChanged(currentDate);
} else {
  displayImage = Image2;
}
}
```

Comment: Your render function must return some sort of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render function is suppose to be pure function, i.e it should not change the state.

React re-renders every time a state is changed, thus setState in a render functions throws into a infinite loop of rendering.

More here: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render

Update the state even before the component is mounted using componentWillMount() life cycle method

Read more :
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

This SO answers may give more insight:[ReactJS - Does render get called any time "setState" is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called)