# Good approach to managing nested state in React

Tags: reactjs

EDIT: I rewrote this question to clarify what I'm after - thank you to the people who have responded so far helping me hone it.

I am trying to understand how best to manage complex, nested state in React, while also limiting the number of times `render()` is called for components whose content has not changed.

As background:

Suppose I have state with both "authors" and "publications" in an object like this:

```
{
  'authors' : {
    234 : {
      'name' : 'Alice Ames',
      'bio' : 'Alice is the author of over ...',
      'profile_pic' : 'http://....'
    },
    794 : {
      'name' : 'Bob Blake',
      'bio' : 'Hailing from parts unknown, Bob...',
      'profile_pic' : 'http://....'
    },
    ...more authors...
 },
 'publications' : {
    539 : {
      'title' : 'Short Story Vol. 2',
      'author_ids' : [ 234, 999, 220 ]
    },
    93  : {
      'title' : 'Mastering Fly Fishing',
      'author_ids' : [ 234 ]
    },
    ...more publications...
  }
}
```

In this contrived example the state has two main areas, accessed by the `authors` and `publications` keys.

The `authors` key leads to an object keyed on an ID of the author, which leads to an object with some author data.

The `publications` key leads to an object keyed on the ID of the publication that has some publication data, and an array of authors.

Suppose my state is in an `App` component with child components like the following pseudo JSX:

```
...
<App>
  <AuthorList authors={this.state.authors} />
  <PublicationList authors={this.state.authors} publications={this.state.publications} />
</App>
...

...
class AuthorList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let authors = this.props.authors;
    return (
      <div>
        { Object.keys( authors ).map( ( author_id ) => {
          return  <Author author={authors[author_id]} />;
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
...

...
class PublicationList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let publications = this.props.publications;
    let authors = this.props.authors;
    return (
      <div>
        { Object.keys( publications ).map( ( publication_id ) => {
          return  <Publication publication={publications[publication_id]} authors=authors />;
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
...
```

Assume `AuthorList` has a bunch of child `Author` components, and `PublicationList` has a bunch of child `Publication` components that render the actual content of those things.

Here is my question: Suppose I want to update the `bio` for a given author, but I don't want `render()` to be called for all the `Author` and `Publication` objects whose content have not changed.

From this answer:

[ReactJS - Does render get called any time "setState" is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called)

A React component's `render()` function will get called any time its state, or the state of any of its parents, change - regardless of whether that state change has anything to do with the props of that component.  This behavior can be changed with shouldComponentUpdate.

How people handle complex state like the above - it doesn't seem like calling render() on large numbers of components on every state change is a good solution (even if the resulting rendered object is the same and so no change occur to the actual DOM).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thank you to jpdeatorre and daveols for pointing me at Redux.

Here is an example application (with tons of corner cutting, but it shows the technique) of using Redux to isolate components from state changes that are irrelevant to them.

In this example the changes to the author Alice with id 1 don't cause `Author` components that don't depend on Alice to have their render() called.

This is because Redux's supplied `shouldComponentUpdate` for its connected react components evaluates whether the props and if relevant state have changed.

Be forewarned that Redux's optimization here is shallow.  To determine wither or not to skip `render()` Redux's `shouldComponentUpdate` checks if:

- The old and new props are `===` to one another
- Or, if not that they have the same keys and the values of those keys are `===` to one another.

So it could result in `render()` being called for components whose values are still logically equivalent however the props to those components and their first level keys do not compare as equal with `===`.  See: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/utils/shallowEqual.js

Note also that in order to prevent calling `render()` on the "dumb" component of `Author` I had to `connect()` it to Redux to enable Redux's `shouldComponentUpdate` logic - even though that component is doing nothing at all with the state and just reads its props.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

import update from 'immutability-helper';


const updateAuthor = ( author ) => {
  return ( {
    type : 'UPDATE_AUTHOR',
    // Presently we always update alice and not a particular author, so this is ignored.
    author
  } );
};

const updateUnused = () => {
  return ( {
    type : 'UPDATE_UNUSUED',
    date : Date()
  } );
};

const initialState = {
  'authors': {
    1: {
      'name': 'Alice Author',
      'bio': 'Alice initial bio.'
    },
    2: {
      'name': 'Bob Baker',
      'bio': 'Bob initial bio.'
    }
  },
  'publications': {
    1 : {
      'title' : 'Two Authors',
      'authors' : [ 1, 2 ]
    },
    2 : {
      'title' : 'One Author',
      'authors' : [ 1 ]
    }
  }
};

const initialDate = Date();

const reduceUnused = ( state=initialDate, action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case 'UPDATE_UNUSED':
      return action.date;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const reduceAuthors = ( state=initialState, action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case 'UPDATE_AUTHOR':
      let new_bio = state.authors['1'].bio + ' updated ';
      let new_state = update( state, { 'authors' : { '1' : { 'bio' : {$set : new_bio } } } } );
      /*
      let new_state = {
        ...state,
        authors : {
          ...state.authors,
          [ 1 ] : {
            ...state.authors[1],
            bio : new_bio
          }
        }
      };
      */
      return new_state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const testReducers = combineReducers( {
  reduceAuthors,
  reduceUnused
} );

const mapStateToPropsAL = ( state ) => {
  return ( {
    authors : state.reduceAuthors.authors
  } );
};

class AuthorList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { Object.keys( this.props.authors ).map( ( author_id ) => {
          return <Author key={author_id} author_id={author_id} />;
        } ) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
AuthorList = connect( mapStateToPropsAL )(AuthorList);

const mapStateToPropsA = ( state, ownProps ) => {
  return ( {
    author : state.reduceAuthors.authors[ownProps.author_id]
  } );
};

class Author extends React.Component {

  render() {
    if ( this.props.author.name === 'Bob Baker' ) {
      alert( "Rendering Bob!" );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Name: {this.props.author.name}</p>
        <p>Bio: {this.props.author.bio}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Author = connect( mapStateToPropsA )( Author );


const mapStateToPropsPL = ( state ) => {
  return ( {
    authors : state.reduceAuthors.authors,
    publications : state.reduceAuthors.publications
  } );
};


class PublicationList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log( 'Rendering PublicationList' );
    let authors = this.props.authors;
    let publications = this.props.publications;
    return (
      <div>
        { Object.keys( publications ).map( ( publication_id ) => {
          return <Publication key={publication_id} publication={publications[publication_id]} authors={authors} />;
        } ) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
PublicationList = connect( mapStateToPropsPL )( PublicationList );


class Publication extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log( 'Rendering Publication' );
    let authors = this.props.authors;
    let publication_authors = this.props.publication.authors.reduce( function( obj, x ) {
      obj[x] = authors[x];
      return obj;
    }, {} );

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Title: {this.props.publication.title}</p>
        <div>Authors:
          <AuthorList authors={publication_authors} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
  return ( {
    changeAlice : ( author ) => {
      dispatch( updateAuthor( author ) );
    },
    changeUnused : () => {
      dispatch( updateUnused() );
    }
  } );
};

class TestApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <span onClick={ () => { this.props.changeAlice( this.props.authors['1'] ); } }><b>Click to Change Alice!</b></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <span onClick={ () => { this.props.changeUnused(); } }><b>Click to Irrelevant State!</b></span>
        </p>

        <div>Authors:
          <AuthorList authors={this.props.authors} />
        </div>
        <div>Publications:
          <PublicationList authors={this.props.authors} publications={this.props.publications} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
TestApp = connect( mapStateToPropsAL, mapDispatchToProps )( TestApp );

let store = createStore( testReducers );

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TestApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById( 'test' )
);
```

Comment: Hmm... not sure why you would put an answer to your questions which is practically the same as what I said.

Comment: Because these two answers are not practically the same.  Yours results in all Author children of AuthorList being re-rendered whenever the state of anything in state.authors changes.  Mine selectively re-renders only the children of AuthorList that have changed content, which is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to accomplish this efficiently and in a readable way using **Object Spread Syntax**.

```
let state = {
    authors : {
        ...this.state.authors, 
        [ givenId ] : { 
            ...this.state.authors[ givenID ], 
            bio : newValue 
        }
    }  
}
this.setState(state)
```

Please remember that you have to pass a 'key' as a prop when you map items in jsx.

This is mainly because, reconciliation ( React's "diffing" algorithm to check what has changed ) thing that react does checks keys for mapped jsx ( roughly naming it jsx ).

Anyway, managing state in reacts state/setState or in redux is irrelevant to 'reconciliation'.

In both cases, you could change the part of a nested data using 'Object Spread Syntax' syntax.

All you would care about the rest is to pass 'identical' keys to the mapped jsx. So that, although react rerenders, it does not try to make dom updates to unnecessary parts, which is expensive.

Comment: Doesn't this re-render everything that depends on anything anywhere in the state?  I do appreciate the nicer syntax for making the update - but if I have to re-render every component each time I change the bio of one author it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I found this answer helpful in understanding what is going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called - by default a component's render() function will get called any time its state, or the state of any of its parents, change - regardless of whether that state change has anything to do with the props of that component.  This behavior can be changed with shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the virtual DOM and how react doesn't change the DOM unless underlying components are different. Nonetheless if I have, say, 50 authors and 100 publications, I don't want to run render() 150 times when the content of only  a few components have changed.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an [immutability helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper), per [React's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html). This provides a mechanism for updating part of the state, and handles any required cloning for you, with as little duplication as possible.

This allows you do something like:

```
this.setState(update(this.state, { authors: { $set: { ... } } }));
```

It will only re-render components that are affected by the change.

Comment: In this instance aren't you creating a new object and overwriting the entire state with it?  Won't this re-render every single object that depends on anything in the state - even though the actual change was isolated to way down in this.state.authors['342'].bio?

Comment: I don't know how it works internally, but based on my reading of the React documentation, it uses shallow copies where possible (and I assume re-uses unchanged references).

Comment: I found this answer helpful in understanding what is going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called - by default a component's render() function will get called any time its state, or the state of any of its parents, change - regardless of whether that state change has anything to do with the props of that component.  This behavior can be changed with shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: I thought React was smarter than that, but I guess not. There's some some info at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html and https://blog.javascripting.com/2015/03/31/turbocharge-your-react-application-with-shouldcomponentupdate-and-immutable-js/ about overriding `shouldComponentUpdate` to manually optimize.

Answer (score 2):

I think using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) would make your app efficient and easier to manage.

Having a global state referred to as *Redux store*, it allows any of your component to subscribe to a slice of the store and re-render when there are changes to those data.

In your example, the redux way of implementing it would be your `AuthorList` component will subscribe to the `state.authors` object and if any component within or outside the `AuthorList` component updated the `state.authors`, only the `AuthorList` component will re-render (and those that are subscribed to it).

Answer (score 0):

Your component state should only really contain internal state values.

You should look into storing more complex state that is needed in multiple components with [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux).

Answer (score 0):

According to [react state management libraries](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/awesome-react-state-management) list for 2023, you could use Redux.

In Redux, all of your nest state could be stored in a single global "store".