# How to prevent react from re-rendering the whole component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I adapted the following component definition from [here](http://recharts.org/#/en-US/examples/CustomActiveShapePieChart) as shown below. However, unlike the example my component re-renders every time I move the mouse on it.

The re-rendering is very noticable:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PieChart, Pie, Sector } from 'recharts';
import { Segment, Header, Dimmer, Loader, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const renderActiveShape = (props) => {

const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
const { cx, cy, midAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius, startAngle, endAngle,
    fill, payload, percent, value } = props;
const sin = Math.sin(-RADIAN * midAngle);
const cos = Math.cos(-RADIAN * midAngle);
const sx = cx + (outerRadius + 10) * cos;
const sy = cy + (outerRadius + 10) * sin;
const mx = cx + (outerRadius + 30) * cos;
const my = cy + (outerRadius + 30) * sin;
const ex = mx + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 22;
const ey = my;
const textAnchor = cos >= 0 ? 'start' : 'end';

return (
    <g>
        <text x={cx} y={cy} dy={8} textAnchor="middle" fill={fill}>{payload.name}</text>
        <Sector
            cx={cx}
            cy={cy}
            innerRadius={innerRadius}
            outerRadius={outerRadius}
            startAngle={startAngle}
            endAngle={endAngle}
            fill={fill}
            />
        <Sector
            cx={cx}
            cy={cy}
            startAngle={startAngle}
            endAngle={endAngle}
            innerRadius={outerRadius + 6}
            outerRadius={outerRadius + 10}
            fill={fill}
            />
        <path d={`M${sx},${sy}L${mx},${my}L${ex},${ey}`} stroke={fill} fill="none" />
        <circle cx={ex} cy={ey} r={2} fill={fill} stroke="none" />
        <text x={ex + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 12} y={ey} textAnchor={textAnchor} fill="#333">{`PV ${value}`}</text>
        <text x={ex + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 12} y={ey} dy={18} textAnchor={textAnchor} fill="#999">
            {`(Rate ${(percent * 100).toFixed(2)}%)`}
        </text>
    </g>
);
};

export default class TwoLevelPie extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeIndex: 0 }
    this.onPieEnter = this.onPieEnter.bind(this);
}

onPieEnter(data, index) {
    this.setState({
        activeIndex: index
    });
}

render() {

    const data = [{ name: 'Group A', value: 400 }, { name: 'Group B', value: 300 },
    { name: 'Group C', value: 300 }, { name: 'Group D', value: 200 }];

    return (
        <Segment inverted>
            <PieChart width={800} height={400} onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}>
                <Pie
                    activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
                    activeShape={renderActiveShape}
                    data={data}
                    cx={300}
                    cy={200}
                    innerRadius={60}
                    outerRadius={80}
                    fill="#8884d8" />
            </PieChart>
        </Segment>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: It may help you get good answers if you make your code [runnable on-site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-reactjs-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support).

Comment: Didn't know that thanks I will try now.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that you change the state every time you do a mouseover (`onPieEnter`)?

Comment: Yes, but how is it working for the example ? @DimitrisKaragiannis

Comment: @Cemre I cannot see the react structure of it in my dev tools. Are you sure it does not re-render even when you hover over the same sector? You would not notice it even if it did.

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis I edited the post showing the re-render in action. It renders in every kind of mouse interaction

Comment: @Cemre Well, I am not sure friend. It seems as if yours does a full re-render, while the example only updates the active section. Have you, by any chance added any transitions to your pie chart? That could also explain the visual effect.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Pure components defined as function will always re-render.

Convert the component to a class and prevent  the re-render in [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) returning false.

The signature is `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`. Say, you prevent re-render by verifying that componet's params haven't changed:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
   return !equals(nextProps, this.props); // equals() is your implementation
}
```

Comment: "Pure components defined as function will always re-render" this is correct. The moment new props get passed down it re-renders.

Comment: Do you mind giving some hints on how to do the rerender in `shouldComponetUpdate` ? I am  bit new to react

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis I've modified the answer. Still I'd like to post the link from the doc.

Comment: So, I moved it to another class and calling it as

`activeShape={<RenderActiveShape />}` and using  `shouldComponentUpdate` as you suggested but now it does not update at all. The label around the pie should still be moving.

Comment: I've opened the fiddle and see what you want to achieve. Please how you use your component.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, 're-rendering' does not mean that the actual DOM gets re-rendered every time a `setState` happens. The virtual DOM is the one that is *always* re-rendered when a `setState` happens. If the previous and current state of the virtual DOM differ, that's when the actual DOM gets re-rendered/updated as well. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called) question and answers

Comment: Where does this `equals` come from?

Comment: @JacobIRR I'd also like to know.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty @JacobIRR `equals()` is a method that you have to implement. It should define your "version" of equality.

Comment: Thank you. This was clearly explained and really helped me.

Comment: regarding "Pure components defined as function will always re-render" -> in React 16.6 you can wrap those in React.memo() to avoid that (unless obviously the properties changed)

Comment: `!equals()` could be `!Object.is(nextProps, this.props)`

Comment: Here I am in 2020 using hooks and this aswer do worked  and saved my day!

Comment: Thanks, this saves a ton!! I had a similar issue and it was actually caused by incorrect use of the router. Previously, the component was passed into <Route> as "component" prop, and the value was a anonymous arrow function. After changing component to the children of the <Route> fixes the problem.