# How to prevent React from re-rendering the whole component when using setInterval

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, rerender

I'm developing an app player. see the picture below:

[image: app player]

The progress bar must show the current time, but with every tick of `setInterval()`, my component re-renders everything. That's causing my app to be slow.

This is my code:

```
this.state = {
    currentTime: 0,
}


/// ....
const tick = 100;
setInterval(() => {
   this.setState({currentTime += tick});
}, tick);


render() {
   // This will call every tick (100ms). That's what I don't want, but if I skip it, the progress will not show the current time.
}
```

Comment: I assume that it is a single component, right? If so, how about creating two children components, with one parent component? One child will render the player, another will render the bottom progress bar. In such a case, setting the state for the 2nd child should not affect the 1st.

Comment: @Yossi: yes, the same result if separate to two children components

Comment: Please post the code that includes 3 components.

Comment: I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763031/how-to-prevent-react-from-re-rendering-the-whole-component).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all. I've resolved my problem by separate to children components. And dispatch to redux store to set currentTime for every stick in setInterval() function. Now it's work like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return false;  
  }
```