# Is React smart enough to bypass setState if I pass in the same value as the current state?

Tags: reactjs

I am setting multiple states in setState, but one of the states will not always change though. Is React smart enough to bypass setting that state it remains unchanged?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you're talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS - Does render get called any time "setState" is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called)

Answer (score 2):

No, by default React will update your component with every `setState` call.
You can use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to let the component know that it shouldn't update when certain conditions are met.

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // If these match, we know we don't need a redraw
    if (this.state.foo === nextState.foo) return false;
    // Otherwise, continue with the update
    return true;
}
```

Note that `shouldComponentUpdate` doesn't affect child-components, who will each check their own update conditions when they receive new props or new state.

You can read more about the React component lifecycle [over here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).