# How to avoid re-rendring of 10000 imageComponent after changing of redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react+redux. I have 100000(example) `ImageComponent` inside a parent component let's say, `ImageGrid`. Functionality on every `ImageComponent` is, user can like, delete and select.

The problem is, when I like, delete or select any single ImageComponent, I update it's state in redux and upon every single state change, it renders the whole 100000 `ImageComponent`.

How to avoid this unnecessary re-rendering of those `ImageComponent` which has not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to the `ImageComponent` to prevent it from re-rendering if its props/state has not changed.

If your props are shallow, you can declare it as `React.PureComponent`. If `ImageComponent` is connected to Redux, then this is automatically done (no re-rendering if `mapStateToProps` return the same props).

You probably shouldn't be rendering 10000 components at once though. Try [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized).

Also you should provide a [unique and stable key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for each component.

Answer (score 0):

shouldComponentUpdate() can be used to prevent the default rendering problem

Official doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

[Here is a post about this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called)