# State change event inside render function is getting called when a different state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react. So for me when some react states get updated. All other state change event inside my return function gets called.

For example :

My State :

```
  state = {
    isLogined  : false,
    redirect: false,
    username: "",
    avatar : '',
    name : '',
    messages : [],
    feeds : [],
    activechat : {},
    currentRoom : '',
  }
```

So I'm listening a firebase database with child_added event and updating my feeds state by using the following code,

```
this.setState({
            feeds : topics
          })
```

It works fine for the feeds component. But all other component associated with other states are getting called again,

```
  <HomeBar avatar={this.state.avatar} />
```

and

```
<Card className={"middleContainer"}>
                {this.getChatBox(this.state.activechat)}
          </Card>
```

So how can i fix that :(

Pastebin for Home and HomeBar

https://pastebin.com/R4G2YCmY

Comment: Which type of component did you use? Can you show the entire component that contains the above state?

Comment: @VuHuuCuong I have added my code to this pastebin https://pastebin.com/R4G2YCmY

Comment: Also added the HomeBar component

Comment: For testing I have added that console.log(props) to HomeBar. And it's calling everytime some change in state occurs

Answer (score 0):

By default, whenever a component is dirty (its state changed), that component and its children are re-rendered.
See -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719289/2092817