# setState unexpectedly updates non-state properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if this is a known issue or an intended feature, but I have found an interesting problem.

So we all know that if we want to render a reactive value in React, we have to put the value in the state and use setState:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { counter: 0 }
  this.incrementButtonListener = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }));
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
      // When clicked, counter increments by 1 and re-renders
      <button onChange={this.incrementButtonListener}>Increment</button> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

But if we make `counter` as a field property, render() will only catch a snapshot of `counter` when the component is created, and even when `counter` is incremented, the result will not be displayed reactively in render():

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.counter = 0;
  this.incrementButtonListener = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.counter++;
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{this.counter}</h1>
      // When clicked, counter increments by 1 but the difference is NOT rendered
      <button onChange={this.incrementButtonListener}>Increment</button> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Right? Basic stuff.

However, there's an interesting occurence when I try to fiddle around with this code. We keeps counter as a field property and everything else intact. The only difference is that, in the `incrementButtonListener`, I'm going to add a `setState` on `someStateProperty`:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.counter = 0;
  this.incrementButtonListener = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.counter++;
    /*-------------------------------ADD THIS*/
    this.setState({});
    // You have to pass an object, even if it's empty. this.setState() won't work.
    /*-----------------------------------------*/
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{this.counter}</h1>
      // Surprise surprise, now this.counter will update as if it was in the state! 
      <button onChange={this.incrementButtonListener}>Increment</button> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

**This time, this.counter updates as if it was in the state!**

So my assumption is, every time setState is called (and even with an empty object as a parameter), render() runs again and `this.counter` will get recalculated and, thus, incremented. Of course, it won't be 100% as reactive as a state property. But, in this use case, the only time `this.counter` would change is when I click on the `Increment` button. So, if I put a setState in the listener, it would work as if `this.counter` is in the state.

Now, I'm not sure if this is an accepted behavior or just an unexpected hack, and whether I should make use of it or not. Could anybody help me elaborate this?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Phiboi/69z2wepo/260234/) if you want to see the behavior in action. You can comment out the `this.setState({})` bit in line 7 to see the difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called

Comment: Frankly I don't see _unexpected_ behavior here. React just ensures (by default) that `render` is called after each `setState` call. If you change a member property alongside `setState` call, there's _no surprise_ that `render` outputs _updated_ property's value (since it changes before `setState`).

Comment: you can force render with `this.forceUpdate();` - no need to call it by setState . It's (well?) known possibility but considered as antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't intercepting the change in state, it is causing a re-render, which in turn is causing your incremented instance property to be used. This is by design. Any changes to React state will cause the component to re-render, unless you are using a lifecycle hook to control whether or not that should happen.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 1):

React use `this.state` and `setState` because it has some own purpose.

By using React state mechanism, we got benefit like the verbosity, functional-like programming style which function should be pure and not mutate the data.

Every time you call `setState` it will use the new value instead mutate the existing and make the behavior unpredictable.

Also you could benefit to prevent component re-render or update by utilize `shouldComponentUpdate` which check props/state inside it.

After your apps is getting complicated, then library like `Redux` could  save your ass in the future. For simpler component or apps, React state is enough.

Further reading:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/07/react-state-vs-redux-state/

Answer (score 1):

You can replace setState on forcrUpdate.
If your team use decorative style of code, then never use setState({}) or forceUpdate().
React's authors recommendes make components like pure functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    state = { counter: 0 };

    increment = () => {
        const { counter } = this.state;

        this.setState({ counter: counter + 1 });
    };

    decrement = () => {
        const { counter } = this.state;

        this.setState({ counter: counter - 1 });
    };

    render() {
        const { counter } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{counter}</h1>

                <p>
                    <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment</button>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button onClick={this.decrement}>Decrement</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

I hope this helps you pick react up! let me know if you have any questions :)