# Change in 1 state property triggers re render of whole element and all children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component with its state like this:

```
var db = {
    one: {
        name: 'xyz',
        color: 'blue',
        seen: false
    },
    two: {
        name: 'abc',
        color: 'red',
        seen: false
    },
    ........and so on many objects
};

this.state = { ...db };
```

Now when i update only 1 of these objects, all of the parent element is re rendered. how can i avoid this and only render that part which changed. How should i set state (which way/method) so that the shallow comparison that react does returs true only for that particular element object and not for the whole state object?

currently, this is how i am setting my state:

```
this.setState(state => {
    state[objectKeyName] = _editedObject;
});
```

Comment: Do i understand correctly: When the parent rerenders, you want some of its children to rerender, but others to not rerender? If so, the child components will likely need to have `shouldComponentUpdate` methods added to them. Hard to give details without seeing those child components though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS - Does render get called any time "setState" is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. React's shallow comparison (via `PureComponent`) will simply check whether the object is different. Since *it is different*, it triggers a re-render. There's no way for it to know "what" to re-render, as in some kind of partial render.

Your best bet is either to make the children `PureComponent`s themselves or apply some behavior via `shouldComponentUpdate`. You'd still trigger the parent render, but the children would be smart enough not to re-render.

As a note of warning, I'd advise against trying to be *too* clever here. You can easily make things more complicated and less performant at the same time. React's renderer works via a virtual DOM diffing, so if the actual DOM rendering of a component isn't changing, it's not going to do much. You still have the overhead of re-rendering the virtual DOM and checking for differences, of course, so it makes sense to use `PureComponent`/`shouldComponentUpdate` in places if you can. But it's not like React is expensively recreating your entire HTML all the time.

There's a lot of documentation around that talks about best practices to avoid re-rendering. [This one](https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html) seems to be what you're looking for.