# Render issue caused by setState executed every 0.1 sec in setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, setinterval, setstate

I'm trying to click on a div that has the onClick function associated with it, but the function doesnt getting called due to the fact that I have a setState inside a setInterval called every 0.1 sec. This updates the DOM and doesnt let me call the function onClick.

I tried to use PureComponent and React.memo to avoid re-renders nested Components, but it didn't work; I could not use them properly though.

Inside the father constructor I have, basically, this:

```
setInterval(()=> { 
    this.setState({state1: 0})
    }, 100)
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm proud of showing you the minimum (almost) code to test the issue (note the functional component: if you remove it and replace the < F /> with its content, it will work properly. Also, if you debug with google chrome, you will see what's going on the DOM):

```
 class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {state1: 0}
        setInterval(() => {this.setState({state1: this.state.state1 + 1})}, 100)
      }

      render() {
        const F = () => (
          <button onClick={()=> alert("this function will be called... sometimes")}> 
              test: {this.state.state1}
          </button>
        )
        return <div> <F/> </div>
      }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

If I write the functional component as a pure function, it will work. here's the example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { state1: 0}
    setInterval(() => {this.setState({state1: this.state.state1 + 1})}, 100)
  }

  render() {
    const F = ({state1}) => (
      <button onClick={()=> {alert("called sometimes")}}> test (will be called sometimes): {state1} </button>
    )

    function f(state1) {
      return <button onClick={()=> {alert("called always")}}> test(will be called always): {state1} </button>
    }

    return <div> <F state1={this.state.state1}/> {f(this.state.state1)}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the interval defined?

Comment: You should provide more info on your question... How you call the `onClick` event,  how `setInterval` defined, how you use the pure component and so on.

Comment: more info added

Answer (score 0):

setState will, by default rerender components that are impacted by said state.

[This was answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719289/7338799)

I would suggest moving away from setting state that often. That's quite expensive and I'm betting there is a far more efficient way to accomplish whatever it is that you're trying to do without the interval.

Comment: There are some good alternatives to execute multiple setState without using setInterval? Btw I tried shouldComponentUpdate but it didnt work neither

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React 16.8^ then you could use Hooks to make multiple state changes. Note that instead of using `setInterval` i used `setTimeout` for each cycle

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const App = (props) => {
    const [numberShown, setNumberShown] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => setNumberShown(numberShown + 1), 100);
    }, [numberShown]);

    return (<div>
       {numberShown}
    </div>)
}
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT :** I found a way to do it the Component Way:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {state1: 0}
        this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this)
        this.startTimer()
    }
    startTimer = () => {
        setInterval(() => {this.setState({state1: this.state.state1 + 1})}, 100)
    }
    render() {
        return <button onClick={()=> alert("this function will be called... sometimes")}>
            test: {this.state.state1}
        </button>
    }
}
```

By experimenting i noticed that if you render the button like this:

```
  render() {
    const F = () => (
      <button onClick={()=> alert("this function will be called... sometimes")}> 
          test: {this.state.state1}
      </button>
    )
    return <div> <F/> </div>
  }
```

Instead of directly returning the `button` tag, the nested onClick function triggering the alert won't always go off but if you do it like in my example it will always trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I state that i dont know how it works exactly with Hooks, but if I add a functional component on render method, I have the same problem

Comment: Changed some thing in case you missed it. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Yes, I checked it; the problem here is that it works without the intermedial functional component (I wrote the "note the functional component" concept on Edit part), the challenge should be to find a way to work with it. I found a way to do this and i'm preparing to write an "Edit 2" part