# React re-rendering components twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a working "Todo" list implementation currently that's using Rails for a backend API and React for the frontend (Along with axios to make requests). Im familiar with Rails but React is still new to me.

Currently I have 4 Components, but the 2 I'm concerned with are `List` and `ListItem`.

`List.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ListItem from './ListItem';


class List extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            listItems: [],
            newItem: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`/api/v1/lists/${this.props.list.id}/list_items.json`)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                listItems: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    addNewListItem = (list_id, content) => {
        axios.post(`/api/v1/lists/${list_id}/list_items`, {
            content: content
          })
        .then(response => {
            const listItems = [ ...this.state.listItems, response.data ]
            this.setState({
                listItems: listItems,
                newItem: ''
            })

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    removeListItem = (listItem_id) => {
        axios.delete(`/api/v1/list_items/${listItem_id}`)
        .then(response => {
            const listItems = this.state.listItems.filter(
                listItem => listItem.id !== listItem_id
            )
            this.setState({listItems})

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ newItem: e.target.value });
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div  key={this.props.list.id}>
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h4 className="card-title">{this.props.list.title}</h4>
                    <p className="card-text">{this.props.list.description}</p>
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {this.state.listItems.map( listItem => {
                        return <li className="list-group-item" key={listItem.id}><ListItem listItem={listItem} removeListItem={this.removeListItem}/></li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="...." value={this.state.newItem} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </div>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-1" onClick={() => this.addNewListItem(this.props.list.id, this.state.newItem)}>Add Item</button>
                        <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm mx-1" onClick={() => this.props.onUpdateList(this.props.list.id)}>Update</button>
                        <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm mx-1" onClick={() => this.props.onRemoveList(this.props.list.id)}>Erase</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default List;
```

`ListItem.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const ListItem = (props) =>
    <div className="list-item" >
        {props.listItem.content}
        <button className="float-right btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" onClick={() => props.removeListItem(props.listItem.id)}>Delete</button>
    </div>

export default ListItem;
```

`ListContainer` wraps around `List` however that's not the issue im facing. It seems that when I add an item to my List, it causes a refresh of the entire page (I can see the styling go away for a second). I tried to take a sample video but unfortunately the video doesn't show it since it happens so quickly.

I can tell the screen is refreshing because when I watch the console and "preserve log" I see this:

> VM412:1 XHR finished loading: POST
>   "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lists/8/list_items".

then

> Navigated to http://localhost:3000/?

So it seems like after I POST to my API (and update the state) what I feel like is happening is that it's re-rendering on the `addNewListItem` AND on the `componentDidMount`. Maybe im mis-using `componentDidMount` but it made the most sense to pull in the "most updated" items when the component mounts.

It's odd that it's getting re-called though? Shouldn't `componentDidMount` only get called once? (I can tell in my console it's getting called again after the `AddNewListItem` runs based on console logs. Or maybe it's working fine and this is just some weird browser glitch from running locally?

Comment: react re-renders on setState as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719289/4775199

Comment: @KyleCalica-St Right, which is what I expect....but a full page refresh is happening which seems odd?

Comment: @msmith1114 indirectly we can say yes it renders two times. first time when component mounts and second time if you set state value then again rerenders happen

Comment: @msmith1114 if entire page is reloading then it has some issue.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar Based off the `Navigated to http://localhost:3000/?` im guessing somehow the whole page is refreshing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you place buttons in forms and do not specify a type they will default to `submit`, causing your page you reload as they try to call the `form` action. Make a habit of always specifying the button type - `<button type="button">`.

For the button which actually submits the form, set the type to `submit` and handle the event with `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` and remember to call `event.preventDefault()` in there to stop the page reloading. You should not handle submit buttons with `onClick` this is bad practice as it isn't accessible (Return key won't submit the form). But `onClick` is fine for non submitting actions.

You should also wrap your `ListItem` in memo as currently every item is re-reconciling even though only one item changed - `export default React.memo(ListItem)` which is the functional equivalent of `React.PureComponent`.

Comment: Ah! that makes sense. I fixed it by doing also `onClick={(e) => this.addNewListItem(e,this.props.list.id, this.state.newItem)}` and then calling `e.preventDefault()` but your way seems much better!.

Also I am not familiar with memo's so I will have to read up on that!