# Component renders 4 times in console.log

Tags: react-native, expo, react-lifecycle

First, thanks for reading me. I'm working on react-native using Expo. I set up functions in my app using componentWillMount and componentDidMount.
It's working, ok but I have difficulties understanding why my component renders 4 times...

I get this result (with my console.log) :

> Results retrieveDeviceManufacturer() :  42
>   ===>retrieveProfileUserId 42 Results retrieveDeviceUID() :  ... Results retrieveDeviceOSVersion() :  10 Results
>   retrieveDeviceManufacturer() :  Google Connection type wifi Is
>   connected? true

But 4 times in a row each times I execute the component. 
I'm of course new to react-native and need help to fully understand this.

Thanks a lot if you can help. Here is my full page of code :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isFirstConnection: true };
    status: "0";
    deviceOSVersion: null;
    deviceManufacturer: null;
    deviceUID: null;
    profileUserId: null;
  }

  performTimeConsumingTask = async () => {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("result");
      }, 1000)
    );
  };
  componentWillMount = async () => {
    this.setState({ deviceOSVersion: await retrieveDeviceOSVersion() });
    this.setState({ deviceManufacturer: await retrieveDeviceManufacturer() });
    this.setState({ deviceUID: await retrieveDeviceUID() });
    this.setState({ profileUserId: await retrieveProfileUserId() });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ status: "6" });
    // Preload data from an external API
    // Preload data using AsyncStorage
    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();

    if (data !== null) {
      this.setState({ isFirstConnection: false });
    }

    Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf")
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.status == "6") {
      console.log(
        "Results retrieveDeviceManufacturer() : ",
        this.state.profileUserId
      );
      if (this.state.profileUserId !== null && this.state.profileUserId > 0) {
        // OK
      } else {
        // Need connection
      }
      console.log("===>retrieveProfileUserId", this.state.profileUserId);

      // Device UUID
      console.log("Results retrieveDeviceUID() : ", this.state.deviceUID);
      if (this.state.deviceUID !== null) {
        // OK
      } else {
        // TODO : next step...
        storeDeviceUID(getDeviceUID());
      }

      // Detect Manufacturer : iOS, Android, ..
      if (this.state.deviceManufacturer !== null) {
        // OK
      } else {
        storeDeviceManufacturer(getDeviceManufacturer());
      }

      // Get system version
      if (this.state.deviceOSVersion !== null) {
        // OK
      } else {
        storeDeviceOSVersion(getDeviceOSVersion());
      }

      console.log(
        "Results retrieveDeviceOSVersion() : ",
        this.state.deviceOSVersion
      );
      console.log(
        "Results retrieveDeviceManufacturer() : ",
        this.state.deviceManufacturer
      );

      NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
        console.log("Connection type", state.type);
        console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
      });
      if (this.state.isFirstConnection) {
        return <SplashScreen />;
      }
      return <Navigation />;
    } else {
      console.log("STATUS INITIALISATION");
      this.setState({ status: "1" });
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the reason why your console.log prints 4 times inside the render fnuction is because you have added 4 setState functions inside the componentWillMount ,

```
componentWillMount = async () => {
    this.setState({ deviceOSVersion: await retrieveDeviceOSVersion() });
    this.setState({ deviceManufacturer: await retrieveDeviceManufacturer() });
    this.setState({ deviceUID: await retrieveDeviceUID() });
    this.setState({ profileUserId: await retrieveProfileUserId() });
  };
```

So every instance of setState will again re-render the app , that is call the render function again , so it's a bad practice and hence render function is called 4 times. try writing everything in on SetState,

```
componentWillMount = async () => {
        this.setState({ deviceOSVersion: await retrieveDeviceOSVersion(),deviceManufacturer: await retrieveDeviceManufacturer() ,
deviceUID: await retrieveDeviceUID(),profileUserId: await retrieveProfileUserId()});

      };
```

And try using comopnentDidmount in place of componentWillMount since it will be deprecated. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from your code, in the `componentWillMount` you are calling `setState` 4 times. Generally speaking, whenever there is a change of state using `setState`, React is going to rerender the component. You are calling it 4 times - you get 4 rerenders (that's one possibility).

[For additional info please refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called)

I would not worry about it until you start to notice problems with the performance of your app, in which case I would think about optimization. But not beforehand.

Moreover, `componentWillMount` has been deprecated and you shouldn't be using it in your components. [Please refer here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Does React re-render all components and sub components every time setState is called?

the default answer is yes.