# Do react functional and class components render differently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

When I use a react functional component with some state manager (I'm using recoil.js) and I try to update the state with a react hook it only calls useEffect when the state is *different* than the original state.
When I was looming on stack overflow on how components rerender, they were talking about class components, and how they render every time setState is called. Is this just a difference between how the two components type work or am I just misunderstanding it?

This was my code test for function components:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {atom, useRecoilState, RecoilRoot} from 'recoil'

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RecoilRoot>
            <App />
        </RecoilRoot>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

const testAtom = atom({
    key: "test",
    default: ""
});

function App(){
    return (
        <>
            <C1 />
            <C2 />
        </>
    );
}

function C1(){
    const [test, setTest] = useRecoilState(testAtom);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('effected', 'c1');
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {setTest('c1')}}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    );
}

function C2(){
    const [test, setTest] = useRecoilState(testAtom);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('effected', 'c2');
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {setTest('c2')}}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    );

}
```

Running this useEffect is only called when the state is changed, not just when setTest is called, but this person [said otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719294/14000710) for class components.

> React doesn't compare state data. When setState is called, it marks the component as dirty (which means it needs to be re-rendered).

Does this mean if I were to make this a class component that it would conoslelog every time?

Comment: No. A react component is a react component. They rerender when state and/or props update. The render method of a class-based component is akin to the entire body of a functional component. React hooks are called every render, in the same order they are declared.

Comment: You actually can make a class component and check your self - they render the same way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. I wouldn't say "they render differently", but there is a difference between how it is determined *when* to renrender a component. I understand how one could expect that the default behavior is the same, however, I also understand that introducing a new state system (`useState`) gave the developers an opportunity to improve the default behavior.

I don't know how recoil works specifically, but I would assume it behaves at least like `useState` wrt rerendering the component. From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update):

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the [Object.is comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)

So this confirms your observation.

But let me be clear: This is not a characteristic of function components, that's just how `useState` works. You could develop your own state management hook which behaves differently.

Now looking add `class` components, from the [`setState` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` will always lead to a re-render unless `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns `false`

And about [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate):

> Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> `shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to `true`.

The first part isn't as clear (*"The default behavior is to re-render on every state change"*, but is setting the same value a "change"?), but the second paragraph makes it clear. `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `true` by default, so the component will always rerender when `setState` was called.

If you implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to call `Object.is` you would replicate the behavior of `useState`.