# Why is my component being rendered again if I pass the previous state value in the setState method?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand the `useState` hook in React. When the below component renders for the first time, it prints `0`. When I click `Button2`, it prints `1`. Now, when I click `button1`, after pressing `button2`, why is the `App` component being rendered again even though I am passing the same value? However when I click the `button2` again, the component is not re-rendered again.

```html
<script type="text/babel" defer>
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  console.log(val);
  const clickHandler1 = () => {
    setVal((prevState) => prevState);
  }
  const clickHandler2 = () => {
    setVal((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Edit to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={clickHandler1}>Button 1</button>
      <button onClick={clickHandler2}>Button 2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using StrictMode? https://andreasheissenberger.medium.com/react-components-render-twice-any-way-to-fix-this-91cf23961625#:~:text=The%20reason%20why%20this%20happens,effects%20in%20the%20render%20phase.

Comment: @JoelHager See snippet - behavior can be reproduced without strict mode

Comment: I think this is what you're asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718709/reactjs-does-render-get-called-any-time-setstate-is-called

Comment: No, I am not using StrictMode.