# Does react re renders after all state objects are updated or does it re render immediately after one state object is updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [a, set_a] = useState();
const [b, set_b] = useState();


const callback = async () => {
  const res = await api_call()

  set_a(res.data.a); // A
  set_b(res.data.b); // B
}
```

Will the above component re render immediately after `a` is updated, or will the component wait until the entire `callback` is completed before re rendering?

Comment: React batches state updates. see: [Queueing a Series of State Updates](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates)

Comment: Also mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71772322/